# Meeting a friend at Heathrow

Tags: airports, london, lhr

My friend and I are flying to London separately.  One on American Airlines (terminal 3); one on United (Terminal 2B).  Our flights are scheduled to arrive about the same time.  When we go through customs, collect our luggage and get to the arrival hall will we end up in the same place?  If not, where is the best place to get together and get the transportation we have arranged for.

Comment: What arrangement have you made for meeting your transportation?

Comment: Have not made it yet, since I wasn't sure to tell him to meet us.

Answer (score 3):

> **When we go through customs, collect our luggage and get to the arrival hall will we end up in the same place?**

No. T2 and T3 have separate arrivals halls.

T3 and T2B are different buildings about 500m apart. You can walk between them.

[image: Map of terminals 2,2b,3]
https://maps.heathrow.com/

> **where is the best place to get together and get the transportation we have arranged for.**

That depends what transportation you have arranged and where your transportation is going to be waiting.

You might want to meet somewhere central.